# How to use Powershell to resursively search user's reporting structure for first enabled manager

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Working on an HR project at work to handle user terminations with PS code. Current challenge is to:
1. Test the user account if enabled/disabled.
2. If Disabled, test their manager's SAMAccount if enabled/disabled.
3. Repeat until an account is found enabled
4. Return that account's SAMAccount.

Working code thus far:

```
$testuser = "johndoe"
If ($(get-aduser $testuser).enabled -eq $true{
$usermgr1 = get-aduser $testuser -properties * | select @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).SAMAccountName}}
}
```

The output of the above is formatted as below. I definitely don't want the header either.

```
Manager
------
JaneDoe
```

I then tried to expand this to the first test, seeing if the manager's account is enabled or not:

```
If ($get-aduser $usermgr1).enabled -eq $true) | select @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).SAMAccountName}}
Else Write-Host "Manager Account  Disabled"
}
```

This attempt returns an error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:4 char:18
 + If ($(get-aduser $usermgr1).enabled -eq $true){write-host "Enabled"}
```

The expected output here is the SAMAccount of this user's manager if enabled; if disabled, I would continue adding more levels to the code up to four or five. I don't yet know enough powershell to loop back and re-test dynamically in order to avoid hardcoding it.

-EDIT-

Using itchydon's example, I opted to limit the recursion at two levels above the target user. The probability of three or more levels all being disabled simultaneously is low. Therefore the working code is:

```
$testuser = "janedoe"
$user = get-aduser $testuser -properties manager
    if ($user.enabled -eq $false){
    $usermgr1 = get-aduser $user.manager
        if ($usermgr1.enabled -eq $true){Write-Host $usermgr1.SamAccountName}
            else{
            $user1 = get-aduser $usermgr1 -properties manager
            if ($user1.enabled -eq $false){
                $usermgr2 = get-aduser $user1.manager
                if ($usermgr2.enabled -eq $true){
                Write-Host $usermgr2.SamAccountName}
                else{Write-Host "Recursion cannot complete. Handle manually."}
                }
            }
}
```

-EDIT-

Now with the working code, trying to set mailbox properties with the same logic. What I'm noticing is the set-mailbox command is executing on the first test, regardless if the manager is disabled or not:

```
if ($user.enabled -eq $false){
            $usermgr1 = get-aduser $user.manager
            if ($usermgr1.enabled -eq $true){
            $mgr1 = $usermgr1.SamAccountName
            $mgr1email = get-aduser $mgr1 -properties EmailAddress
            $mgr1email.emailaddress
            }
        Set-Mailbox $testuser -ForwardingAddress $mgr1email.EmailAddress -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $False
        Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $testuser -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage $internal -ExternalMessage $external
        Write-Host $testuser "Completed"
       }
        else{
```

In this case, the test whether $usermgr1.enabled -eq $true fails, and I would expect the set-mailbox commands to be skipped entirely, moving on to the else{ statement.

I thought it was just a matter of moving the commands inside the test declaration like so:

```
   if ($user.enabled -eq $false){
            $usermgr1 = get-aduser $user.manager
            if ($usermgr1.enabled -eq $true){
            $mgr1 = $usermgr1.SamAccountName
            $mgr1email = get-aduser $mgr1 -properties EmailAddress
            $mgr1email.emailaddress
            Set-Mailbox $testuser -ForwardingAddress $mgr1email.EmailAddress -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $False
            Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $testuser -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage $internal -ExternalMessage $external
            Write-Host $testuser "Completed"
            }
       }
        else{
```

However, the end result of that when the enabled test passes is that the set-mailbox commands are skipped entirely, and no action is taken at all.

-EDIT-
Fixed the mailbox commands problem by leaving variable declarations in their own block like so:

```
$user = get-aduser $testuser -properties manager
    if ($user.enabled -eq $false){
            $usermgr1 = get-aduser $user.manager
            $mgr1 = $usermgr1.SamAccountName
            $mgr1email = get-aduser $mgr1 -properties EmailAddress}

    if ($usermgr1.enabled -eq $true){
            Set-Mailbox $testuser -ForwardingAddress $mgr1email.EmailAddress -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $False
            Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $testuser -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage $internal -ExternalMessage $external
            Write-Host $testuser "Completed"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to test this unfortunately but I think this is what you are after.

```
$testuser = "johndoe"    
$user = get-aduser $testuser -properties manager
if ($user.enabled -eq $true){
    $usermgr1 = get-aduser $user.manager
    if ($usermgr1.enabled -eq $false){
        Write-Host "Manager Account  Disabled"
    }
    else{
        write-host $usermgr1.samaccountname
    }
}
```

In the above rather than keep doing a `get-aduser` we do it once for the testuser  and save it to a variable (`$user`).  We can then access each property of the object - so we use this to check the enabled status as shown e.g. `$user.enabled -eq $true`. If true - do another `get-aduser` for the manager's information using the same technique

Comment: Thank you Itchy; updated the original question expanding on the problem with your suggestion incorporated. Short version is that now commands are either executing when they shouldn't, or not when they should. Probably just a logic error.

Comment: Yep, for the most part. Curiously the script appears to have gone rogue on one record where the user account was in fact enabled at the time. I had thought the first line of .enabed -eq $false would have resulted in any enabled account being skipped. Is it necessary to explicitly declare this condition at the end of the script? I assumed it could be ignored and the script would just exit completely if that first condition failed.

Comment: Not sure I follow. At present it's  if ($user.enabled -eq $false){
            $usermgr1 = get-aduser $user.manager